# Set up multiple file using crontab using PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I'm working on setting up cronjobs using PHP script. I know how to set up single file as a crontab,  for example - shell_exec('crontab testcron.txt');

Is it possible to set multiple files as a crontab, like -

shell_exec('crontab testcron1.txt testcron3.txt testcron2.txt');
shell_exec('crontab testcron1.txt,testcron2.txt,testcron3.txt');

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

no, you can only have one file per user

but you can add multiple cronjobs in one crontab file.
One cronjob per line.